# How to disable Hiera debug output in rspec-puppet test

Tags: rspec, puppet

I have the following spec file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'PLC', :type => 'class' do

  let(:hiera_config) { 'spec/fixtures/hiera/hiera.yaml' }
  hiera = Hiera.new({ :config => 'spec/fixtures/hiera/hiera.yaml' })

  abc = hiera.lookup('PLC::PLC_LINE',nil,nil)

  let(:hiera_data) {{
    :PLC_LINE => abc
  }}

  it{ should contain_file('/test/rspec/etc/PLC').with(
        'ensure'  => 'file',
        'owner'   => 'root',
        'group'   => 'root',
        'mode'    => '0644',
        'require' => 'File[/test/rspec/etc]') }

  it{ should contain_file('/test/rspec/etc/PLC').with_PLC_LINE(abc)}


end
```

below is my `/hiera/fixtures/plc.yaml`

```
plc : puppetlab
```

when I run `rake spec`, the following messages get printed:

```
DEBUG: Wed Jul 08 07:11:55 -0400 2015: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: Wed Jul 08 07:11:55 -0400 2015: Looking up plc::plc_LINE in YAML backend
DEBUG: Wed Jul 08 07:11:55 -0400 2015: Looking for data source plc
```

How can this output be suppressed?

Comment: Those are debug messages, not errors. Are there errors, which you have not shared yet?

Comment: only debug no error message. Even I tried similar hiera for another module sepcs but getting same error "DEBUG: Tue Jul 21 04:40:53 -0400 2015: Hiera YAML backend starting DEBUG: Tue Jul 21 04:40:53 -0400 2015: Looking up test_services in YAML backend DEBUG: Tue Jul 21 04:40:53 -0400 2015: Looking for data source testDEBUG: Tue Jul 21 04:40:53 -0400 2015: Found test_services in test"

Comment: Again, those are *not* error messages. Are you asking how to get rid of the debug output?

Comment: Yes, why is it throwing this message. Wanna to remove when I run the test rspec.

Comment: OK, I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put into e.g. `spec_helper.rb` following:

```
Puppet::Util::Log.level = :warning
```

On client you can easily check the `log_level`:

```
puppet config print log_level --section agent
```

You can modify this in e.g. `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` (depend on path to your configs):

```
[agent]
log_level = info
```

Comment: Thanks. But why it's throwing debug warning when I run did test

Comment: If you run `puppet agent -t` it shouldn't display debug messages (unless you've configured log level differently).